# tab completion missing, ll not found, logout not found

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

Hallo I just have a VPS provisioned with Ubuntu 14.04.5

I already had a VPS provisioned and working fine, with the same provider.

This time, I'm experiencing some issues:

- **bash completion not working, neither history command (arrow up); moving cursor across the line with left/right arrow results in
  character codes being printed (eg. `^[[C` )**: already tried
  installing/reinstalling bash-completion, updating .bashrc, logging
  off and on; even if the login shell for the user is bash, I tried
  `chsh`. No luck.
- **some commands missing**: ll, logout, they give me `sh: ll: not found`
- **some other minor differences**: like the cwd path missing from the prompt

Could these facts altogether be of same meaning to you?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `sh: ll: not found` really does suggest this is a sh versus bash issue - are you testing this in a gnome-terminal or in a CLI environment? Did you confirm that `chsh` changed your login shell (e.g. `getent passwd $USER`)?

Comment: Are you sure you are running bash at all? If `set |grep BASH` does not produce tons of output, you are not running bash. One reason could be that /bin/sh is linked to something other than bash.

Comment: ... or that you've set your terminal emulator preferences to use /bin/sh explicitly

Comment: in the meanwhile I ran a
`sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude full-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential -y`
and now everything is ok. Sounds weird to me.